# Congruence in localization of rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Please help me to prove for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$, $(aR/a^2R)_\mathfrak{m}\cong (aR)_\mathfrak{m}/(a^2R)_\mathfrak{m}\cong aR_\mathfrak{m}/a^2R_\mathfrak{m}$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with 1 and $a\in R$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because localization is exact.

Comment: Would you mind giving the detail please?

Comment: Is this working: $\frac{(ax+a^2R)}{b} \to \frac{(ax)}{b}+(a^2R)_\mathfrak{m}\to a\frac{x}{b}+a^2R_\mathfrak{m}, b\in R-\mathfrak{m}$?